# Migrate a composer app to wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, composer-php

I wrote a small php script that uses composer libraries (autoload) und I want to create a WordPress plugin from it.

So in the first step I moved the app into the wp-content/plugins/ folder and pasted the plugin information into the index.php

When i call the plugin files directly everything is working fine. But when i want to activate the plugin it gives me this warning:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::setPsr4() in /Users/arbeitsplatz17/mywordpresssite/wp-content/plugins/mbot-for-woocommerce/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:33
>
> Stack trace: #0 /Users/arbeitsplatz17/mywordpresssite/wp-content/plugins/mbot-for-woocommerce/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit7ac7e564af60fe6cf77aaa4603b98681::getLoader()
> 1 /Users/arbeitsplatz17/mywordpresssite/wp-content/plugins/mbot-for-woocommerce/index.php(36): require_once('/Users/arbeitsp...')
> 2 /Users/arbeitsplatz17/mywordpresssite/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(1964): include('/Users/arbeitsp...')
> 3 /Users/arbeitsplatz17/mywordpresssite/wp-admin/plugins.php(164): plugin_sandbox_scrape('mbot-for-woocom...')
> 4 {main} thrown in /Users/arbeitsplatz17/mywordpresssite/wp-content/plugins/mbot-for-woocommerce/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 33

The only function that calls the autoloader is:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

I don't know much about composer. I have used the following repository as the base and modified it for my needs:
https://github.com/pimax/fb-messenger-php-example